# delete a node in linked list doesn't work in c

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I want to delete a node from a linked list .but it doesn't work . here is my code :

```
jL Delete(jL* node,int n)
{
jL first1, n_th, save;
int count = 0;
save = first1 = n_th = (*node);
while(first1->next)
{
   first1 = first1->next;
    count++;
    if(count == (n-1))
    break;
}


while ( first1->next != NULL )
{
    first1 = first1->next;
    save = n_th;
    n_th = n_th->next;
}

save->next = n_th->next;
free(n_th);
return (&node);}
```

where is my mistake ? can you help me please

Comment: No data declarations shown, modifies local copies, returns address of parameter.  That should be enough to be going on with.

Comment: Oh and debugger...........DCV

Comment: I've rolled back your edit - if you want to delete your question, please do so, but don't just remove the code - it makes your question impossible to understand, plus it renders the existing answers useless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the following. I suppose that indices of the elements in the list start from 0.

```
jL Delete( jL* node, int n )
{
    jL current = *node;
    jL prev = NULL;

    while ( current != NULL && n != 0 )
    {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
        --n;
    }

    if ( n == 0 && current != NULL )
    {
        if ( prev == NULL ) *node = current->next;
        else prev->next = current->next;

        free( current );
    }

    return *node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to return a value since the list pointer is updated, or the function could return a pass / fail indicator (fail if n not in list).

```
void remove_node(jL* node, int n)
{
jL *ppNode = node;
jL pNode;
    if(node == NULL || *node == NULL)
        return;
    while(n--){
        ppNode = &((*ppNode)->next);
        if(*ppNode == NULL)             /* if n not in list */
            return;                     /*   just return */
    }
    pNode = *ppNode;                    /* delete node */
    *ppNode = (*ppNode)->next;
    free(pNode);
}
```